# For a positive integer $n$, prove that $\sum_{d|n}{\mu^2(d)/\phi(d)=n/\phi(n)}$

Tags: number-theory

For a positive integer $n$, prove that $$\sum_{d|n}{\mu^2(d)/\phi(d)=n/\phi(n)}$$ I suspect something is missing here. I guess there is on extra condition on $n$, which is $n$ must ne square free. Because when I substitute $n=20$, the equality does not hold. Can anyone clarify for me ?

Comment: I think you are wrong about $n=20$. $d=1,2,4,5,10,20$, but $\mu(d)=0$ if $d=4,20$.  So the sum is $$\frac{1}{\phi(1)}+\frac{1}{\phi(2)}+\frac{1}{\phi(5)}+\frac 1{\phi(10)} = 1 + 1 +\frac 1 4 + \frac 1 4 = \frac 5 2= \frac {20}8 = \frac n{\phi(n)}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to see this is to use that $f(n)=\mu^2(n)/\phi(n)$ is multiplicative, so therefore so is $$F(n)=\sum_{d\mid n} \mu^2(d)/\phi(d)$$

Likewise, $g(n)=n/\phi(n)$ is multiplicative.

So you only need to prove $F(n)=g(n)$ for $n=p^a$ with $p$ prime.

An alternative approach would be to define note that if $n=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$ and $d|n$ square-free, then $$\frac{\phi(n)}{\phi(d)} = \prod_{i} p_i^{a_i-1} \cdot \prod_{p_i\not\mid d} (p_i-1)$$

If we let $n_0=\prod_i p_i$ and $d|n_0$ is square-free, this means that $$\frac{\phi(n)}{\phi(d)} = \frac{n}{n_0} \phi(n_0/d)$$

Now: $$\sum_{d|n} \mu^2(d)\frac{\phi(n)}{\phi(d)} = \sum_{d|n_0} \frac{\phi(n)}{\phi(d)} =\frac{n}{n_0}\sum_{d|n_0} \phi(n_0/d) = \frac{n}{n_0}\sum_{d|n_0} \phi(d) = n $$

Now divide both sides by $\phi(n)$.

Comment: You mean $f(n)=\mu^2(n)/\phi(n)$ or ?

Comment: @Cortizol Yep, fixed.